# Cant compile java code in linux mint, i think java is not properly installed

Tags: java, debian, java-11

I cant compile Java code, it says

```
cannot access java.lang
Fatal Error: Unable to find java lang in class path or bootclasspath
```

I have Jdk installed(Openjdk and Oracle,I am usinig oracle because I was testing alternatives)

```
java version "11.0.5" 2019-10-15 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.5+10-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.5+10-LTS, mixed mode)
```

I tried to install `sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk` but it fails also. I don't have a clue of what is wrong.

```
E.g.:
sudo mkdir -p /var/cache/oracle-jdk11-installer-local
sudo cp jdk-11.0.4_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz /var/cache/oracle-jdk11-installer-local/
sha256sum mismatch jdk-11.0.5_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
Oracle JDK 11 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java11-installer-local (--configure):
 installed oracle-java11-installer-local package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java11-installer-local
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: So do you want OpenJDK, Oracle JDK or both installed?

Comment: Why don't u try to do with this link https://www.wikihow.com/Install-Java-on-Linux

Comment: Thank you, but a managed to resolve removing oracle jdk, changing the enviroment and upadate path to openJdk-8.